# Adding HTML tags to items pulled through a databse using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, database, list

I'm trying to add 'li' tags to objects I am pulling through a database, right now the results appear as unsorted 'item1 item2 item3 item3' with this code:

```
var XML = new Array();     
XML = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;    
alert($(XML).find('ItemName').text());
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you please describe it in few more words ?

Comment: What is your server side language that produce that XML? Might be easier if you could just wrap it from there? :o

Comment: ASP.Net I believe... the database was created by my friend and I'm doing the Javascript part of it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine each ItemName is an object. Each of those objects can be iterated through using the same methods you are using above

```
var eachItem = $(XML).find('ItemName');
$.each(eachItem, function(index,value){
  $("#someContainer").append('<li>'+$(value).text()+'</li>');
  //in the above, 'value' is our object', 'index' is the row # at which our object was found.
});
```

**Edit** - *Edited to reflect needs of OP.*

Comment: Why pass `eachItem` to `$.each()` when you can just call `eachItem.each()` directly?

Comment: So the user has a clear understanding of how we achieved our result. Of course, minifying this is completely different. I feel this is easier to read when explaining, I'm wrong several times in a day in life, though, and this may be one of those times.

Comment: This worked but the results were *[object] *[object] *[object] so I added .text() at the end of the .find function and now I get *I *t *e *m *1 *I *t *e *m *2 etc

Comment: Try using .html(). I don't know what type of data is being returned here.

Comment: .html() creates a blank page, if it helps the data is being pulled from an asp.net database, it's xml data and I don't know how to describe this but it is SOAP.

Comment: Oh for sure, well if the XML data is created in a format that is proper (to say the least) then you would target an attribute within the li tag. such as -> `.append('<li>'+$(value).attr('SomeAttribute')+'</li>');` -- this should do what you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that some more?

Comment: Sure, if you have markup like `<itemname> <someAttribute> My Item Name </someAttribute> </itemname>` then in the above code, i'm literally targetting the attribute of someAttribute within the container <itemname> and for each instance found of itemname, we're printing someAttribute within it.

Comment: hmmm... getting *undefined *undefined *undefined; not trying to be clueless about this but I am.

Comment: _edit_ : you don't have the reputation to chat, just noticed. my bad. Can you show me the structure of your XML?

Comment: <DataSet xmlns="http://site.com/MobileWebService">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="ItemList">
<xs:element name="ItemList" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Item">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ItemName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Comment: <Item diffgr:id="Item1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<ItemID>120</ItemID>
<ItemName>Item 1</ItemName>
</Item>
<Item diffgr:id="Item2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<ItemID>190</ItemID>
<ItemName>Item 2/ItemName>
</Item>

Comment: Let me know if I'm missing anything